# Segmentation fault when calling free

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, free

I making a little server in c. 
I have a segfault when i call free after multiple connections but i can't find out where it come from.

At the beginning i thought it came from realloc but even when it is not called i have the segfault.

```
for (;;) {
        if ((client = accept(sock, NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
            err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Failed to accept client");
        }

        totalBytes = 0;
        int size = 2048;

        char* tmp = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);

        if (tmp == NULL) {
            err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Failed to malloc");
        }

        while ((r = read(client, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) {
            totalBytes += r;

            if (totalBytes >= size) {
                size += totalBytes - size + 1;
                tmp = realloc(tmp, sizeof(char) * size);

                if (tmp == NULL) {
                    err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Failed to realloc");
                }
            }

            buffer[r] = '\0';
            strcat(tmp, buffer);

            ioctl(client, FIONREAD, &r);

            if (r <= 0) {
                break;
            }
        }

        char http_request[size];

        strcpy(http_request, tmp);
        free(tmp);
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `strcat(tmp, buffer);` That results in undefined behaviour because `tmp` contents are uninitialised. `strcat` requires a string as the first arg. Need to init with something like `tmp[0] = '\0''`

Comment: It seems confused, juggling sizes, and `size += totalBytes - size + 1;` has `size` on both sides. There is a `+1` in there, possibly to allow for the `buffer[r] = '\0';` but it's unclear what is what.

Comment: Yes thank you for your comments but I was looking for a way to concat the data readed. But i agree with you the code isn't very well

Answer (score 0):

As kaylum said, this solve my problem

```
tmp[0] = '\0';
```

Thank you